# Is the Python fcntl module different on different Linux kernels?

Tags: python, fcntl

I have a Python script that does locking thru the file system calls using the Python fcntl module.

The script works fine on an Ubuntu 10.10 release.

But if I run the same script on a Centos 6.2 host, the script bombs with the error:

*AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'F_WRLCK'*

The actual code is:

```
    if Cmd['mode'] == 'r':
        lockType = fcntl.F_RDLCK
    else:
        lockType = fcntl.F_WRLCK
```

On the Centos host, the script bombs on the last line.

Why doesn't the fcntl module have a F_WRLCK attribute on the Centos 6.2 kernel but does on the Ubuntu?

FYI, both the Ubuntu 10.10 and Centos 6.2 are running Python 2.6.6.

Is there a workaround or solution to this?  I need to use fcntl and not flock.

Comment: It's possible this is a bug. From some googling, it looks like the CentOS 5 documentation for `fcntl(2)` says that `F_WRLCK` is present.

Comment: "bombs on the last line" How?

Comment: @Ignacio, it throws the AttributeError.  In other words, Python can't find an attribute named fcntl.F_WRLCK

Comment: That's not a OS-level problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, maybe you're right.  I tried running Python interactively.  "print fcntl.F_WRLCK" works -- it displays 1.  Why doesn't the same statement work when I do it programmatically?

Comment: I replaced all the attributes with literals.  Example - fcntl.F_RDLCK was replaced with 0.  I still can't get it to work in a program because Python complains that fcntl.fcntl() is not a callable method.  I tried calling fcntl() instead and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Anybody else have any insight into this?